# Multiple tcp sockets, one stalled

Tags: c++, windows, sockets, networking, tcp

I'm trying to get a starting point on where to begin understanding what could cause a socket stall and would appreciate any insights any of you might have.

So, server is a modern dual socket xeon (2 x 6 core @ 3.5 ghz) running windows 2012. In a single process, there are 6 blocking tcp sockets with default options, each of which are running on their own threads (not numa/core specified). 5 of them are connected to the same remote server and receiving very heavy loads (hundreds of thousands of small ~75 byte msgs per second). The last socket is connected to a different server with a very light send/receive load for  administrative messaging.

The problem I ran into was a 5 second stall in the admin messaging socket. Multiple send calls to the socket returned successfully, however nothing was received from the remote server (should receive a protocol ack within milliseconds) or received BY the remote admin server for 5 seconds. It was as if that socket just turned off for a bit. After the 5 seconds stall passed, all of the acks came in a burst, and afterwards everything continued normally. During this, the other sockets were receiving much higher numbers of messages than normal, however there was no indication of any interruption or stall as the data logs displayed nothing unusual (light logging, maybe 500 msgs/sec).

From what I understand, the socket send call does not ensure that data has gone out on the wire, just that a transfer to the tcp stack was successful. So, I'm trying to understand the different scenarios that could have taken place that would cause a 5 second stall on the admin socket. Is it possible that due to the large amount of data being received the tcp stack was essentially overwhelmed and prioritized those sockets that were being most heavily utilized? What other situations could have potentially caused this?

Thank you!

Comment: Does the server have a nearly-full SSD?

Comment: No, it's pretty barebones and brand new. 23gb used of 65gb partition. 2 disk 150gb onboard raid1. I also considered disk, but the logger is in it's own thread, and wrote without any hiccups during the stall.

Comment: Welcome to TCP/IP. The possibilities for delays are almost limitless. I'm not kidding here. TCP guarantees delivery, but it does not guarantee when. Don't use it for time-critical messages. Delay in retransmission of a few lost packets due to congestion control is the most likely candidate.

Comment: It's conceivable that the kernel was so busy handling interrupts caused by the inbound data that it wasn't able to process the outbound data, which is done at a lower priority level than the interrupt handling. *Or* that the admin peer was slow reading so its receive window was closed so the outbound data couldn't be transmitted at all.

Comment: @user4581301, yea but 5 seconds? From reading on Windows TCP transmission delays, from what I understood, the max wait time should be 200ms.

Comment: @EJP, do you have any reference for the first part of your comment? As far as your second, the admin peer is not slow reading, and there are not that many messages received on it (maybe 1 per second).

Comment: It's just common sense. Presence of data in the socket send buffer doesn't constitute an interrupt, so it must be handled at a lower priority level.

Comment: Exponential backoff in the TCP congestion control can turn 200ms into 5 seconds with a few lost packets if the right packets or their acks are lost. Say after 200 ms, a packet is resent and lost The next try may be 600 ms (total 800 ms) later. If that's lost the next retry may be after 1800 ms (total 2.6 seconds) and if that one is also lost 5.4 seconds (total 8 seconds) is not out of the question. This is an unfortunate extreme and most likely much shorter delays are in effect, but what if you had a run of bad luck and lost 10 packets?

Comment: I should add that there are a whole slew of mechanisms that try to keep the data moving as fast as possible (The spice must flow!) that short-circuit backoff. [Give this a read](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TCP_congestion-avoidance_algorithm)

Comment: You should use wireshark to see what is really being put on the wire during those 5s delay. You can also see if the admin data is perhaps subject to loss and retransmission. In those situations a delay of 5s is understandable because the retransmission timer is increasing all the time. Also when there is packet loss, the window size is going to be influenced. Slower speeds as a result.

Comment: @user4581301 thank you for that explanation, i see your point now. assuming that is the problem, do you think turning off Nagle with TCP_NODELAY would help?

Comment: Nagle deals with a different issue. It delays sending a small message to see if another small message can be bundled with it into the same TCP packet. Thousands of 75 byte messages a second will certainly fill a packet before Nagle becomes a 5 second lag. Turning off Nagle could result in those 75 byte messages all being sent individually rather than accumulated and sent. Every packet sent adds at least 50 bytes of overhead and costs the network hardware and CPU processing time. When sending massive amounts of small messages, Nagle is your friend.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the sockets are receiving hundreds of thousands of 75-byte messages per second there is a possibility that the server is at maximum capacity with some resources. Maybe not bandwidth, as with 100K messages you might be consuming around 10Mbps. But it could be CPU utilization.

You should use two tools to understand you problem:

- perfmon to see utilization of CPU (user and priviledged https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa173932(v=sql.80).aspx) , memory, bandwidth, and disk queue length. You can also check number of interrupts and context switches with perfmon.
- A sniffer like Wireshark to see if at TCP level data is being transmitted and responses received.
- Something else I would do is to write a timestamp right after the send call and right before and after the read call in the thread in charge of admin socket. Maybe it is a coding problem.

The fact that send calls return successfully doesn't mean data was immediately sent. In TCP data will be stored in the send buffer and from there, TCP stack will send the data to the other end.

If your system is CPU bound (you can see with perfmon if this is true), then you should put attention to the comments written by @EJP, this is something that could happen when the machine is under heavy load. With the tools I mentioned, you can see if the receive window in the admin socket is closed or if it is just that socket read is taking time in the admin socket.